Lie theory--Hall's equation
Someone introduced the following to me as Hall's equation: if $x,y,z$ are three elements in a group $G$, then
$$[[x,y],^{y}z][[y, z], ^{z}x][[z, x], ^{x}y] = 1.\tag{1}$$
Here $[a,b] = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, and $^{g}h = ghg^{-1}$. One easily checks this; the pattern of cancellation is rather nice.
Question. Does there exist a "differential'' or Lie theoretic interpretation of (1)?
I think the formal resemblance to Jacobi triple product is obvious. Thinking about the triple product formula in a Lie algebra as a Leibniz rule for the commutator bracket, I tried to write $[ab, c]$ in terms of $[b,c]$ and $[a,c]$ and found
$$[ab,c] = ^{a}[b,c][c, a^{-1}]\tag{*}$$
Don't know if it's relevant. My suspicion is that in thinking of it this way, I'm fatally mixing up the group and algebra sides of the Lie correspondence. At the same time, it seems probable that at least in the case $G$ is a Lie group, (1) has some nontrivial geometric interpretation.

If $a\in L$, then what is $a^{-1}$ in the Lie algebra?

I don't know. (*) is still a formula in an abstract group

The Jacobi identity is $[a,[b,c]]+[b,[c,a]]+[c,[a,b]]=0$. Your product is different.
